# How do I change the colour of my title in Baposter in latex?

Tags: color, titles, baposter

I am making a poster using the `baposter` document class. The background of my poster is dark, and since the title is `black` by (default), the title is very hard to read. I would like to make my title white so the contrast is better. I tried doing this:
title `Color=white!100`,
but it didn't change anything.
Is there a way to change the colour of the title?

Comment: There is no special color for title, therefore the easiest solution would be to include command `\color{<whatevercolor>}` before the title in baposter's title section.

Comment: @Ross The headerFontColor is defined as used for the subheadings so your suggestion does not answer the main header whereas Ignasi is correct simply inject the colour over-ride at point of application i.e. just before the text so if using overleaf template change `{\sf\bf` to `{\sf\bf\color{white}`